# Using Git locally with a bare origin and push requests

Tags: git

I'm working on a server where multiple users have access to the same files on a single machine. I do not want to host anything online, so everything should be local.

I have a central bare origin `Code_bare` a clone with the stable version `Code_stable` and then user-specific development branches: `Code_UserA`, `Code_UserB`...

How would I restrict push permissions from user branches to the bare repository? I don't/can't use GitHub because of security and want to avoid paying for a subscription to GitLabs.

Comment: You're creating a *lot* of unnecessary difficulty for yourself by trying to deviate from how this is normally done.  Why do you believe you need any user to be able to directly edit the origin?  Why not use a bare origin, and make your `Code` repo a clone just like all the others?  As for access control, you could use hooks, or you could use a server like GitLab or GitHub to host the server and set up access control per their models.  Relying on the non-bare checkout restirctions absolutely will not work reliably, especially if you have more than one branch.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yes, I see now, that makes more sense. I updated the question to be more concise. How would I achieve the access control if I can't use GitHub and want to avoid GitLabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've ruled out using a hosting environment for your origin repo.  While there are many options of hosting software, and these have more user-friendly interfaces for managing access control (among other things), they aren't for everyone.  So in that case, you'd presumably use a pre-receive hook to do access control.

A hook is just a script that runs at a particular time.  The pre-receive hook runs when someone pushes to the repo, and its exit status decides if the push is accepted.

The first challenge, then, is how to authenticate the user (since things like committer name and email are set at the client's discretion).  I guess the simplest option would be to only accept commits that have been signed by particular user(s) on `master`, but if you weren't planning to use signatures this may seem like overkill.  Another option is to only accept pushes by ssh, in which case I believe you can get the username from the environment variables.

Once you've authenticated the user, you can check whether `master` (or any other branch you want to protect) is in the list of updated refs, and if so decide whether to accept the push or not based on your authorization rules.

But to be clear, this approach is all "put together a script that does it"; git's support for this only goes so far as "it will execute the script you give it before deciding whether to accept the push".  Which brings us back to the advantage of using hosting software.